# C# Function Overloading in the New .NET 6 Console Template is Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console

I am getting errors trying to overload the function `Print(object)` in the [new .NET 6 C# console app template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) (top-level statements).

```cs
void Print(object obj) => Print(obj, ConsoleColor.White);

void Print(object obj, ConsoleColor color)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

Errors are:

- From `Print(obj, ConsoleColor.White)` -> `No overload for method Print() that takes 2 arguments`
- From `Print(object obj, ConsoleColor color)` -> `A local variable or function named 'Print' is already defined in this scope`

I tried to switch their order but it still throws errors.  What's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Contents of top-level is assumed to be an internals of `Main`, so you declared two *local* functions inside `Main`. And local functions does not support overloading.

You can:

- switch to the old style template with full specification of class

  ```
  class Program
  {
   static void Main(){}

   void Print(object obj) => Print(obj, ConsoleColor.White);

   void Print(object obj, ConsoleColor color)
   {
      Console.ForegroundColor = color;
      Console.WriteLine(obj);
      Console.ResetColor(); 
   }
  }
  ```
- to stay with new template, but wrap your function into the separate class

  ```
  var c = new C();
  c.Print("test");

  public class C{
    public void Print(object obj) => Print(obj, ConsoleColor.White);

       void Print(object obj, ConsoleColor color)
       {
          Console.ForegroundColor = color;
          Console.WriteLine(obj);
          Console.ResetColor(); 
       }
  ```

  }

Related github isse with some technical details: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/28231