# Why is method overloading not working in this program?

Tags: c#, overloading

Program.cs contains only this code (no `Main()`-method):

```
Console.WriteLine(Add(10, 12));
Console.WriteLine(Add(1.5, 2.9));

static int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;

static double Add(double a, double b) => a + b;
```

The compiler tries to use the `înt`-version of the `Add()`-method in both method calls, and naturally throws the "Cannot convert from 'double' to 'int'"-error on the two arguments of the second call.

Why isn't method overloading working? The parameter types are different in the two methods.

It works if I paste the code into dotnetfiddle.net, but not in Visual Studio.

**Update**

This works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Add(10, 12));
        Console.WriteLine(Add(1.5, 2.9));
    }

    static int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;
    static double Add(double a, double b) => a + b;
}
```

Comment: _"Program.cs contains only this code (no Main()-method):"_ - it _does_. You just don't _see_ it.

Comment: Post the link to that fiddle, please.

Comment: You should also get an additional error - "A local variable or function named 'Add' is already defined in this scope", because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72234567/5133585).

Comment: Are you perhaps using the "Script" project type in dotnetfiddle? That is different from projects you create in VS, and has its own quirks.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Of course it works if you declare the two methods outside of the `Main` method, but see this fiddle, which is equivalent to what OP did, it doesn't work. And it also gives exaclty the error, Sweeper mentioned ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/SY4TSl

Comment: Local functions do not support method overloading, just put the methods outside of the main method.

Comment: got it @derpirscher. Deleted my previous comment

Comment: And that's exactly why I don't like this "feature".

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I think I was using the "scripts" project type in dotnetfiddle. I can't get into dotnetfiddle at the moments. Seems to be down.